# Existe uma linguagem de "descrição" de UML?

Tags: uml, diagrama, diagrama-de-classes

Pode ser uma pergunta bem boba, mas eu pesquisei e não achei nada no sentido em que estou pensando. Estou estudando UML na faculdade, e apesar de ser só arrastar os componentes pra formar os diagramas, esse procedimento pode ser meio chato (principalmente ter que ficar organizando tudo).

Existem linguagens de descrição de hardware (como VHDL e Verilog), em que você descreve o circuito a ser gerado, semelhante a uma linguagem de programação. Assim, estava pensando que talvez seria mais fácil para analistas criarem os diagramas UML de forma semelhante...

Já existe algo assim para UML?

Comment: Meio que daria na mesma, o mesmo trabalho que você teria pra arrastar, você teria pra criar o código..... O que pode ser mais útil nesse caso, é saber se a ferramenta que utiliza possui um botão pra organizar o UML automaticamente

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616126/auto-arrange-uml-diagrams-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Leila a anos atrás quando estava na faculdade utilizei uma ferramenta online que você enviava um xml de metadados e ele montava o diagrama de classes para você. Eu não me lembro bem mas não era só o diagrama de classe montava outros tb. Era bem legal!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse post parece que é exatamente o que deseja:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302239/free-plugin-to-generate-a-class-diagram-from-a-xml-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [yUML](https://yuml.me)

Já usei essa ferramenta que serve para alguns tipos de diagramas e tem a vantagem de você poder compartilhar e ter plugins para várias plataformas.

Um exemplo:

**Código para Diagrama de Classes:**

```
[Customer|-forname:string;surname:string|doShiz()]<>-orders*>[Order]
[Order]++-0..*>[LineItem]
[Order]-[note:Aggregate root{bg:wheat}]
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Código para Caso de Uso:**

```
[Customer]-(Sign In)
[Customer]-(Buy Products)
(Buy Products)>(Browse Products)
(Buy Products)>(Checkout)
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Outro que descobri quando estava usando esse foi o [UMLGraph](https://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/), mas não cheguei a utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Ultimate, Enterprise Architect, StarUML, ArgoUML, UModel até mesmo MSVisio tem funcionalidade para converter código em UML.

Geralmente há limitações, tanto destas quanto de outras opções, no tocante à linguagem de programação suportada. Em termos práticos, funcionam muito bem se você precisar de um diagrama de classes e de sequência, já que esta notação é muito próxima do código-fonte orientado à objetos em termos conceituais.

Porém, cabe ressaltar que UML tem diversos diagramas que são muitos úteis e que não foram concebidos para modalagem bottom-top. Seu poder está na capacidade de abstração que oferece e, portanto, na modelagem top-bottom.

Use à vontade, mas tenha em mente que uma boa prática de programação é começar pelo modelo/arquitetura conceitual do software e não pelo código-fonte.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Tenho utilizado apenas UML para software, mas existem é tools ou addins que utilizam uma especie de scripting para construir os diagramas UML.

Por exemplo:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration